# Need help using CSS to reorder some blocks in Squarespace

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, squarespace

first time poster here, been lurking for some time.

I've been helping my wife build her website as she is starting some freelance service but we have come across an issue that I've spend a good amount of time trying to solve but have miserably failed.

I've tried I don't know how many combinations of classed calling .row .sqs-row .col etc but have not been able to change the order of the blocks in the mobile view of the website.

Site URL: https://yosyvelasquez.com pass:yosydesign2021

While in the desktop the side will display a series of steps as:

1 2 3
4 5 6

[desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy2Rk.png)

however in the mobile view it is showing
1
4
2
5
3
6

[mobile view1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3QVg.png) [mobile view2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgjFk.png)

The last thing I tried is this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
 div#page-section-60482408b332ea04661c1cf0> .row .sqs-row {
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
   
   
  }
 #block-25053f13e7adbb1c828d{order:2 !important;}
}
```

but it is not working, I've changed the code many times. I understand I need to set the display to flex so I can use the order command it just won't seems to work.

I'd really appreciate any help and guidance I can get as I'm a complete newbie in CSS.

Comment: After heading over to the website URL you included, it seems your using Bootstrap in the site as well. Probably best to add the tag to the question too.

Comment: Not sure if I am, might be included/embedded into squarespace itself. I'll include the tag just in case. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome! It seems squarespace is indeed using Bootstrap in this template. I copied the code for that grid portion into a snippet and will post an answer shortly.

Comment: From looking at the code for your six steps, it appears that you created your first block with steps 1 & 4, your second block with steps 2 & 5, and your third block with steps 3 & 6. I don’t know about how content is defined in Squarespace, but could you define six separate blocks, one for each step, rather than three blocks of two steps?

Comment: @RichDeBourke it was squarespace own doing, I've been fighting to not do that but it just works that way it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After copying the code for that grid section from [this link](https://www.yosyvelasquez.com/). The ordering in the HTML was not in sequence. The `04` container came right after the first and the `05` after the second. I see that's how you (or Squarespace) made the columns in that "grid" type layout. After putting the elements into the correct order within your HTML, everything is in order as expected.

If you want to keep the same out of order sequence in the HTML then you could use [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) to ensure the items are in ascending order. Please do keep in mind the following:

> Using the order property will create a disconnect between the visual presentation of content and DOM order. This will adversely affect users experiencing low vision navigating with the aid of assistive technology such as a screen reader. If the visual (css) order is important, then screen reader users will not have access to the correct reading order.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex div {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.one {
  order: 1;
}

.two {
  order: 2;
}

.three {
  order: 3;
}

.four {
  order: 4;
}

.five {
  order: 5;
}

.six {
  order: 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="one">
    <h2>01</h2>
    <h3>Obtén una cotización</h3>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="four">
    <h2>04</h2>
    <h3>Desarrollo de Proyecto</h3>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <h2>02</h2>
    <h3>Agenda tu proyecto
</h3>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="five">
    <h2>05</h2>
    <h3>Revisiones</h3>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <h2>03</h2>
    <h3>Inicio de Proyecto</h3>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="six">
    <h2>06</h2>
    <h3>Finalización de Proyecto</h3>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to add some of your own styling I would recommend using [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) and order the HTML elements correctly in ascending order for those relying on assistive technologies to view the site.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(15rem, 1fr));
  gap: 1.5rem;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  max-width: 110ch;
}

.grid div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <h2>01</h2>
    <h3>Obtén una cotización</h3>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>02</h2>
    <h3>Agenda tu proyecto
</h3>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>03</h2>
    <h3>Inicio de Proyecto</h3>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>04</h2>
    <h3>Desarrollo de Proyecto</h3>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>05</h2>
    <h3>Revisiones</h3>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>06</h2>
    <h3>Finalización de Proyecto</h3>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @nekojosh I would recommend using my second example in terms of accessibility for those relying on a screen reader to view your wife's site. Let me know if this information helps you out.

Comment: I tried both ways you suggested and while they both work I still fight with the way squarespace manages columns. If I introduce a code block for each step then squarespace asumes there are 3 columns even when I have not defined them. If I do a single code block with all the html I can control a move stuff around as intended but the desktop view also shows as a column and I couldn't figure out how to return it to the way it is supposed to look on the desktop.
Also tried to have 2 sections, hide one from the desktop view and vice versa on mobile but content-wrapper still takes the blank space.

Comment: Hey Tanner, thanks for the help. After reading a little about how bootstrap works with layouts on grids I ended up reusing squarespace's code and tweeking it to break the columns into 2 row. That ended up sorting the issue. I only got there thanks to you help and mention of bootstrap. Thanks!